# Python asyncio http request module

Tags: python, python-asyncio, http-redirect, aiohttp

Here is how I'm making a request:

```
    from aiohttp import request
    def make_request(self, request_payload, request_headers, request_method, request_url_path):
        url = self.config["HOST_URL"] + "/" + request_url_path
        response = yield from request(request_method, url=url, params=request_payload, headers=request_headers, allow_redirects=False)
        return response
```

The expected response in case of successful request here is `response status 302` and a `Location` header in response, which will contain the url on which redirect needs to be done.

The issue is, I'm getting response status as 200, which is response from the final url. How can I achieve what I want?

"allow_redirects=False" should have worked, but it doesn't. I'm not sure how can I get it to work as I need.

Answer (score 1):

Note: if you use old generator-based syntax you should use decorator `asyncio.coroutine`. If you're using Python 3.5+ use [new syntax for coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-492-coroutines-with-async-and-await-syntax).

Please provide also minimal code snippet that can be reproduced (including url, other params, your Python version), since I don't get behavior you're talking about:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import request


@asyncio.coroutine
def make_request():
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/redirect/1'
    response = yield from request(method='GET', url=url, allow_redirects=False)
    print(response)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(make_request())
```

Output:

```
<ClientResponse(http://httpbin.org/redirect/1) [302 FOUND]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'meinheld/0.6.1', 'Date': 'Wed, 15 Nov 2017 16:28:55 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '215', 'Location': '/get', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'X-Powered-By': 'Flask', 'X-Processed-Time': '0.000524044036865', 'Via': '1.1 vegur')>
```

Answer (score 0):

Request supports an optional allow_redirects parameter, that you can set to False.

Comment: It's allow_redirects with an underscore, not a hyphen.

Comment: Please go through the entire post, sir. In code, I've used the correct flag.